# JavaFX: How can I create a setUpGUI method?

Tags: user-interface, methods, javafx

I would like to set make a method that sets up the GUI. I tried in this way:

```
public class Test extends Application {
    GridPane root;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {          
        root = setGUI();  
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    private GridPane setGUI(){        
        GridPane root2 = new GridPane();        
        ColumnConstraints cc = new ColumnConstraints();
        RowConstraints rc = new RowConstraints();
        cc.setPercentWidth(10);
        rc.setPercentHeight(10);
        root2.getColumnConstraints().add(cc);
        root2.getRowConstraints().add(rc);
        for(int c = 0; c < 10; c++){            
            int w = (int) root2.getWidth()/10;
            int h = (int) root2.getHeight()/10;
            for(int r = 0; r < 10; r++){
                MyRectangle rec;
                if((r+c)%2 == 0){
                    rec = new MyRectangle(w, h, Color.GREY);
                }else{
                    rec = new MyRectangle(w, h, Color.DARKGRAY);
                }          
                System.out.println("w h "+w+" "+h);
            }  
        }
        return root2;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and in many others but never got the "chess board effect" i wanted. I also tried setting `root2` as `final` and I tried many other changes but didn't manage it!
EDIT:
`MyRectangle` class:

```
package test;

import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public class MyRectangle extends Rectangle{
    public int clickedTimes = 0;
    public MyRectangle(int w, int h, Color c) {
        super (w, h, c);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Can you add the `MyRectangle` class ?

Comment: You are not doing anything with rec variable..

Comment: I did it. It worked as long as all code was in `public void start(Stage primaryStage)` but when i tried to move it out in a method it stopped working

Comment: @Uluk Biy, you are right. i forgot to add it to the grid. It is working now. I'm gonna test it more later. thanks

Comment: How did it work ?? You are not adding rectangle to grid ?

Comment: Acutually, coping it from `public void start()` to `setGUI()` i forgot to copy `root.add(rec, r, c)`. Shame on me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even after you add the rectangles to the grid, it wont work, because of the following lines :

```
int w = (int) root2.getWidth()/10;
int h = (int) root2.getHeight()/10;
```

You are not setting the `Width/Height` of the `Gridpane`, so it will always be **zero** !

You need to set the size of the GridPane and then use it to set the size of the rectangle. A working example :

```
public class Test extends Application {
    GridPane root;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {          
        root = setGUI();  
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    private GridPane setGUI(){        
        GridPane root2 = new GridPane();  
        root2.setPrefHeight(300);//Set Height
        root2.setPrefWidth(300);//Set Width
        ColumnConstraints cc = new ColumnConstraints();
        RowConstraints rc = new RowConstraints();
        cc.setPercentWidth(10);
        rc.setPercentHeight(10);
        root2.getColumnConstraints().add(cc);
        root2.getRowConstraints().add(rc);
        for(int c = 0; c < 10; c++){            
            int w = (int) root2.getPrefWidth()/10;
            int h = (int) root2.getPrefHeight()/10;
            for(int r = 0; r < 10; r++){
                MyRectangle rec;
                if((r+c)%2 == 0){
                    rec = new MyRectangle(w, h, Color.GREY);
                }else{
                    rec = new MyRectangle(w, h, Color.DARKGRAY);
                }          
                System.out.println("w h "+w+" "+h);
                rec.setStyle("-fx-border-color:black; -fx-border-width:1px;");
                root2.add(rec, c, r);
            }  
        }
        return root2;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me why did you use `getPrefWidth()` instead of `getWidth()`?

Comment: As I said, you were setting the size of `scene`, which the gridpane will take only after its set to the scene. The method `setGUI` is called before this, inside which the **size** of the `gridpane` is still not set and will be considered as 0.

Comment: If the answer resolves your problem, do accept it for future references !